# Am I using reader wrong or is it possible my reader has null values?

Tags: c#, .net, reader

I'm working on an e-commerce project and am having a little trouble with the reader. Here is my ShoppingCartController code that is not working

```
public List<PRODUCT> GetCartItems()
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("MyConnection");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspGetCart", sqlConnection1);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<PRODUCT> cartList = new List<PRODUCT>();
        PRODUCT product;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            product = new PRODUCT();
            product.MANUFACTURER.ManufacturerName = reader["ManufacturerName"].ToString();
            product.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
            product.Cost = decimal.Parse(reader["Cost"].ToString());
            cartList.Add(product);
        }
        sqlConnection1.Close();
        return cartList;
    }
```

The error that I'm getting is
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack Trace is

```
    [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
    SeeSharpBeans.Controllers.ShoppingCartController.GetCartItems() in c:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SeeSharpBeans\SeeSharpBeans\Controllers\ShoppingCartController.cs:54
    SeeSharpBeans.Controllers.ShoppingCartController.Index() in c:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SeeSharpBeans\SeeSharpBeans\Controllers\ShoppingCartController.cs:22
    lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +101
    System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
    System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +435
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod() +76
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +36
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102



System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
```

My Product model looks like this

```
public partial class PRODUCT
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public PRODUCT()
    {
        this.PURCHASES = new HashSet<Purchase>();
        this.TRANSACTIONS = new HashSet<TRANSACTION>();
    }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    public virtual MANUFACTURER MANUFACTURER { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Purchase> PURCHASES { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TRANSACTION> TRANSACTIONS { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

Comment: Why are your properties virtual?  Are these entity classes? Why are you explicitly suppressing warnings rather than heeding their advice?

Comment: I used Database first, so that is what Entity Framework created for me

Comment: I tried taking the virtual part out but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data does not contain null values then the likely problem is that you do not initialize the `MANUFACTURER` property to a value in the `PRODUCT` constructor, which means it is null when you attempt to set `product.MANUFACTURER.ManufacturerName` to a value.

Also note that naming classes and members in ALL CAPS is generally bad form - consider changing them to `Product` and `Manufacturer`.

Comment: How do I initialize it in the PRODUCT class?

Comment: Some book told me to do me database classes in all caps, I thought that was garbage, but I was like what do I know, and when I did database first it put the Product and Manufacturer class in all caps

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue might be with the line

```
product.MANUFACTURER.ManufacturerName = reader["ManufacturerName"].ToString();
```

Is MANUFACTURER initialized in Product class?

Comment: Does the virtual initialize it?

Comment: It does not matter whether it virtual or not. You can do something like this: product.MANUFACTURER = new MANUFACTURER(); and then initialize ManufaturerName

Answer (score 0):

Try to move collection item definition into the scope of while loop:

```
while (reader.Read()) 
{ 
PRODUCT product = new PRODUCT(); 
product.MANUFACTURER.ManufacturerName = reader["ManufacturerName"].ToString(); 

product.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();

product.Cost = decimal.Parse(reader["Cost"].ToString()); 
cartList.Add(product); }
```

Comment: Try to elaborate your answer a bit more, so others can easily understand why you have followed that approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
This line is the issue
product.MANUFACTURER.ManufacturerName = reader["ManufacturerName"].ToString();

Use
 product.MANUFACTURER.ManufacturerName = Convert.ToString(reader["ManufacturerName"])  

 product.Cost = decimal.Parse(Convert.ToString(reader["Cost"]));
instead of .ToString();
```

Comment: That gave me the same error. I did a clean and rebuild just to make sure.

Comment: what about this line  
product.Cost = decimal.Parse(reader["Cost"].ToString());

Comment: It doesn't hit that line because it breaks before it

Answer (score 0):

Need to Initialize MANUFACTURER  by using their constructor like :-

```
while (reader.Read())
            {
                product = new PRODUCT();
                product.MANUFACTURER=new MANUFACTURER();
                product.MANUFACTURER.ManufacturerName = reader["ManufacturerName"].ToString();
                product.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                product.Cost = decimal.Parse(reader["Cost"].ToString());
                cartList.Add(product);
            }
```